# Footnotes without indent

Tags: footnotes, indentation

I have already read similar questions, but they did not help.

I use `\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}` and I would like footnotes without indention.

Using `\noindent` does not help. Using this package `\usepackage[hang,flushmargin]{footmisc}` solves the issue, but TeXstudio gives back an error and I can see a little black square at the end of the footnote, which should not appear.

EDIT:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{FB01}{fi}
\usepackage[italian,UKenglish]{babel}
\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[hang,flushmargin]{footmisc}
\author{Bla Bla}
\title{Bla Bla}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{paracol}{2}
\noindent bla bla

\bigskip
\noindent bla bla \footnote{bla bla}.

\switchcolumn
\noindent bla bla

\end{paracol}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If possible, can you provide a MWE for your requirement?

Comment: Sorry, what MWE stands for? The whole code I wrote?

Comment: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that

Comment: I have edited. I don't know if it is clear..

Comment: I’m afraid your Example (as it presently stands) is neither Working, nor Minimal (are all those packages really relevant?).  Besides, it doesn’t show what the problem is, and makes no use of the `footmisc` package.

Comment: @Gum Is footmisc necessary? I did not put the actual text. Yes, I need those packages for my writing.

Comment: 1) Actually, I took it for granted that you were satisfied with solving the issue by means of the `footmisc` package, and were just asking about its (supposed) misbehavior.  2) I meant: are all those packages actually needed for *the example* to reproduce the problem?  3) Strictly speaking, it’s not *necessary* to use `footmisc`, you could also make the necessary patches to the `\@makefntext` command yourself.  4) Please clarify if you want no identation only at the beginning of the footnote, or also at the beginning of every paragraph of the footnote (in case the footnote has more than one).

Comment: I don't want any kind of indentation in footnotes.

Comment: If I use footmisc, I get this error: ! Use of \footnotelayout doesn't match its definition.

Comment: @Alwayslearning: Please post a MWE reproducing the `\footnotelayout` error.

Comment: Now is it more clear? PS. I can't edit with the proper graphics.

Comment: You should highlight your code when you paste it in and hit Ctrl+k, or use the code sample button in the toolbar (the {} next to the big quotation marks)

Answer (score 1):

Both `paracol` and `footmisc` define a command `\footnotelayout`, but their definitions do not agree. One simple way to fix this, assuming you don't need to use that command, is to nullify this command at the start of the `paracol` environment with `\let\footnotelayout\relax`.

```
\documentclass{article} 

\usepackage[hang,flushmargin]{footmisc}
\usepackage{paracol}  

\usepackage[nopar]{lipsum} % just for dummy text  

\begin{document}

\begin{paracol}{2}
    \let\footnotelayout\relax  % this fixes it

    \lipsum[1]\footnote{\lipsum[2]}

    \switchcolumn 

    \lipsum[3]\footnote{\lipsum[4]}                                                                     
\end{paracol} 

\end{document}
```

You can always wrap this in your own environment:

```
\newenvironment{mytwocolumns}
  {\begin{paracol}{2}
   \let\footnotelayout\relax}
  {\end{paracol}}
```

Comment: Do I have to add also this: \usepackage[nopar]{lipsum} and \lipsum as in your example?

Comment: No, as the comment says, that package just provides dummy text to use for an example.

Comment: I put this \let\footnotelayout\relax just after paracol, but it does not change the footnotes.

Comment: @Alwayslearning If you use my exact example it works. The question, then, is what factors are different in your example? What aspect does not change about the footnotes? (Do you mean the black boxes? because that's unrelated to this problem.